# Unable to parse Double from EditText

Tags: java, android

[A picture of the Error is right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BNPD.png)

For some reason, I am unable to parse Doubles from an EditText. 
Every time I enter a number, the EditText isn't able to pick up that I typed anything, but when I type in letters, it can sense that I typed in letters (still threw a NumberFormatException both times.

Here's the relevant code.

**Java**

```
public class rLawCalc extends Fragment
{
    View rootview;
    Spinner spin;
    TextView trial;
    TextView r1;
    TextView r2;
    TextView r3;
    TextView r4;
    TextView A;
    TextView B;
    TextView C;
    TextView D;
    TextView Answer;
    EditText A1;
    EditText A2;
    EditText A3;
    EditText A4;
    EditText B1;
    EditText B2;
    EditText B3;
    EditText B4;
    EditText C1;
    EditText C2;
    EditText C3;
    EditText C4;
    EditText D1;
    EditText D2;
    EditText D3;
    EditText D4;
    Button GO;
    double concA1 = 0;
    double concA2 = 0;
    double concA3 = 0;
    double concB1 = 0;
    double concB2 = 0;
    double concB3 = 0;
    double concC1 = 0;
    double concC2 = 0;
    double concC3 = 0;
    double concD1 = 0;
    double concD2 = 0;
    double concD3 = 0;
    double rateA = 0;
    double rateB = 0;
    double rateC = 0;
    double concA = 0;
    double concB = 0;
    double concC = 0;
    double rate1 = 0;
    double rate2 = 0;
    double rate3 = 0;
    double rate4 = 0;
    int expA;
    int expB;
    int expC;
    boolean onClick = false;
    String resp;
    String spinner = "";
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> choices;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //inflate rootview
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_r_law_calc, container, false);
        //load EditText
        A1 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.A1);
        A1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        A2 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.A2);
        A2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        A3 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.A3);
        A3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        A4 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.A4);
        A4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        B1 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.B1);
        B1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        B2 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.B2);
        B2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        B3 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.B3);
        B3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        B4 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.B4);
        B4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        C1 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.C1);
        C1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        C2 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.C2);
        C2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        C3 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.C3);
        C3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        C4 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.C4);
        C4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        D1 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.D1);
        D1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        D2 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.D2);
        D2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        D3 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.D3);
        D3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        D4 = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.D4);
        D4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //load spinner
        spin = (Spinner) rootview.findViewById(R.id.numReactants);
        choices = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( getActivity(), R.array.numOfReactants, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        choices.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(choices);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                //Made to Test Spinner
//                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                spinner = "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                switch (spinner)
                {
                    case "1":
                        trial = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.Trial);
                        trial.setText(R.string.t1);
                        r1 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                        r1.setText("1");
                        r2 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
                        r2.setText("2");
                        A = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.concA);
                        A.setText("   [A]");
                        B = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.concB);
                        B.setText(R.string.rxnrate);
                        B.setTextSize(15);
                        A1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        A2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        B1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        B2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        GO.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        trial = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.Trial);
                        trial.setText(R.string.t1);
                        r1 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                        r1.setText("1");
                        r2 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
                        r2.setText("2");
                        A = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.concA);
                        A.setText("[A]");
                        B = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.concB);
                        B.setText("[B]");
                        C = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.concC);
                        C.setText(R.string.rxnrate);
                        A1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        A2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        A3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        B1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        B2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        B3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        C1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        C2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        C3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        GO.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;

                    case"3":
                        trial = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.Trial);
                        trial.setText(R.string.t1);
                        r1 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                        r1.setText("1");
                        r2 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
                        r2.setText("2");
                        r3 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
                        r3.setText("3");
                        r4 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tv4);
                        r4.setText("4");
                        A = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.concA);
                        A.setText("[A]");
                        B = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.concB);
                        B.setText("[B]");
                        C = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.concC);
                        C.setText("[C]");
                        D = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.concD);
                        D.setText(R.string.rxnrate);
                        A1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        A2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        A3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        A4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        B1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        B2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        B3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        B4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        C1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        C2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        C3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        C4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        D1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        D2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        D3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        D4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        GO.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please select an Option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        //load Button
        GO = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.GO);
        GO.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                switch(spinner)
                {
                    case "1":
                        case1Ints();
                        Answer = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.Answer);
                        Answer.setText(resp);
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        case2Ints();
                        Answer = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.Answer);
                        Answer.setText(resp);
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        case3Ints();
                        Answer = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.Answer);
                        Answer.setText(resp);
                }
            }
        });
        GO.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return rootview;
    }
    public void case1Ints()
    {
        try
        {
            concA1=Double.parseDouble(A1.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+",""));
            concA2 = Double.parseDouble(B1.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+",""));
            rate1 = Double.parseDouble(A3.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+",""));
            rate2 = Double.parseDouble(B3.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+",""));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException n)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter numbers only", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        double temp = concA2/concA1;
        double rate_change = rate2/rate1;
        if(rate_change == temp)
        {
            resp = "Rate = k[A]";
        }
        else if(rate_change == temp*temp)
        {
            resp = "Rate = k[A]2";
            resp = resp.replaceAll("2", "²");
        }
        else if(rate_change == 1)
        {
            resp = "Rate = k";
        }
        //have to make everything within an acceptable range
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to give number as input?

Comment: Where is your Exception?

Comment: @DeepakM the number input was in the EditText

Comment: @AmiHollander No Exceptions are being thrown any more because I added try/catch, but the number input from EditText still isn't being recognized

Answer (score 1):

Code which i always follows is that and these always helped me i had created scientific calculator and i used these always in my code,

```
EditText refer=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.idofet);
double val=Double.parseDouble(refer.getText().toString());
```

Hope it will help you .

Comment: Yea I have the same code but for some reason the number isn't being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

If you type numbers, without the numeric dot, Java could see it as an Integer. So, before you call parseDouble I would suggest you to convert it to an Integer first. Like: `(double) 
Integer.parseInt(A1.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+",""));`

You also need to add an onTextChanged listener if you want to detect character change. It will work for any character you type.

```
A1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i,
                                          int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1,
                                      int i2) {
               // Here you could parse the entered text
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
});
```

Comment: The main problem with using integer is that most of my input will have decimals and converting it to an int will get rid of that decimal.

Comment: Also, do I need to have the TextChangedListener when I have the button?

Comment: Where is the line you get the text from the textfield?

Comment: Oh wait sry I just added that to the catch{} to make it easier to show exactly what the problem was

Answer (score 0):

i have few suggestions, that you could try:

1. Debug your code and see what is happening when you enter a number/double number
2. check the content of `A1.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+","");` for example see if it reflect the number your trying to parse.
3. if not move upper in your code and see what's going on (use debugger tool)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem is that the app can't recognize the numerical input.

Comment: I added a picture to my original post to show the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

- First you must see if type something in your EditText, when you read
  it with getText() return is correct.

> To see this make comment your code who throw the error and make a
>   TextView and print the return result of getText().

- If it not correct probably (like it is null or "" ) you have bug in
  the reference of the EditText.

Comment: yea in the XML I made the input type numberDecimal

Comment: But for some reason changing .toString to ""+EditText.getText()  didn't change anything